# Find the McLaurin series for $f(x)=x/(x+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Can you help me find the McLaurin of $f(x)=x/(x+1)$ ? I am new to this mathematical chapter and already tried but I do not think my result is correct.

Comment: Around which point?

Comment: it is around 0.

Comment: use the fact $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$ is the sum of a geometric series whose first term is one and what is the ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\frac x{x+1}=\frac x{1-(-x)}$ and write as a geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

Around $z=0$,
$$\frac{z}{z+1}=1-\frac{1}{1+z} = \sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1} z^n.$$